# Generating a numpy-ndarray from dataframe for keras data

Tags: python, pandas, keras, deep-learning, numpy-ndarray

This is a task I have been thinking of how to do it. I have a DataFrame containing motion characteristics of users (by user `id`) similar to the one below:

```
>>> df
   id  speed1  speed2  acc1  acc2  label
0   1      19      12     5     2      0
1   1      10      11     9     3      0
2   1      12      10     4    -1      0
3   1      29      13     8     4      0
4   1      30      23     9    10      0
5   1      18      11     2    -1      0
6   1      10       6    -3    -2      0
7   2       5       1     0     0      1
8   2       7       2     1     3      1
9   2       6       2     1     0      1
```

From this dataframe, I would like to generate a `numpy ndarray` *(should I rather say list of arrays?)* of fixed-length segments by splitting each user's (i.e. `id`) records, so that each segment is of the shape `(1, 5, 4)` that I can feed to neural network this way:

- each segment (thus, the `1`) consists of five arrays (thus, the `5`) of the motion characteristics `speed1 speed2 acc1 acc2` (thus the `4`) in the above dataframe.
- where the rows cannot make-up to five arrays, the remaining arrays are filled-up with zeros (i.e. zero-padded)

Then the `label` column should also be a separate array, matching the size of the new array, by duplicating the `label`´s value in the position of the zero-padded arrays for the padded segments.

In the given `df` example above, the expected output would be:

```
>>>input_array
[
   [
     [19 12 5 2]
     [10 11 9 3]
     [12 10 4 -1]
     [29 13 8 4]
     [30 23 9 10]
   ]
 
   [
     [18 11 2 -1]
     [10 6 -3 -2]
     [0  0  0  0]
     [0  0  0  0]
     [0  0  0  0]
   ]
 
   [
     [5 6 -3 -2]
     [7  2  1 3]
     [6  2  1 0]
     [0  0  0 0]
     [0  0  0 0]
   ]
]
```

- `id=1` has 7 rows, so the last 3 rows are zero-padded. Similarly, `id=2` has 3 rows, so the last 2 rows are zero-padded.

**EDIT**

I noticed 2 bugs with the function given in the answer.

1. The function introduces an all-zero array in some cases.

For example in this:

```
df2 = {
    'id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
'speed1': [17.63,17.63,0.17,1.41,0.61,0.32,0.18,0.43,0.30,0.46,0.75,0.37],
'speed2': [0.00,-0.09,1.24,-0.80,-0.29,-0.14,0.25,-0.13,0.16,0.29,-0.38,0.27],
'acc1': [0.00,0.01,-2.04,0.51,0.15,0.39,-0.38,0.29,0.13,-0.67,0.65,0.52],
'acc2': [29.03,56.12,18.49,11.85,36.75,27.52,81.08,51.06,19.85,10.76,14.51,24.27],
'label' : [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3] }

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df2)

X , y = transform(df2[:10])
X
array([[[[ 1.763e+01,  0.000e+00,  0.000e+00,  2.903e+01],
         [ 1.763e+01, -9.000e-02,  1.000e-02,  5.612e+01],
         [ 1.700e-01,  1.240e+00, -2.040e+00,  1.849e+01],
         [ 1.410e+00, -8.000e-01,  5.100e-01,  1.185e+01],
         [ 6.100e-01, -2.900e-01,  1.500e-01,  3.675e+01]]],


       [[[ 0.000e+00,  0.000e+00,  0.000e+00,  0.000e+00],
         [ 0.000e+00,  0.000e+00,  0.000e+00,  0.000e+00],
         [ 0.000e+00,  0.000e+00,  0.000e+00,  0.000e+00],
         [ 0.000e+00,  0.000e+00,  0.000e+00,  0.000e+00],
         [ 0.000e+00,  0.000e+00,  0.000e+00,  0.000e+00]]],


       [[[ 3.200e-01, -1.400e-01,  3.900e-01,  2.752e+01],
         [ 1.800e-01,  2.500e-01, -3.800e-01,  8.108e+01],
         [ 4.300e-01, -1.300e-01,  2.900e-01,  5.106e+01],
         [ 3.000e-01,  1.600e-01,  1.300e-01,  1.985e+01],
         [ 4.600e-01,  2.900e-01, -6.700e-01,  1.076e+01]]]])
```

Notice how the function introduced an all-zero array as the second element. Ideally the output should contain only the first and last arrays.

2. When passed a df with more than 10 rows, the function fails with an `index can't contain negative values` error.

So  if you `df2` you get this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-71-743489875901> in <module>()
----> 1 X , y = transform(df2)
      2 X

2 frames

<ipython-input-55-f6e028a2e8b8> in transform(dataframe, chunk_size)
     24             inpt = np.pad(
     25                 inpt, [(0, chunk_size-len(inpt)),(0, 0)],
---> 26                 mode='constant')
     27             # add each inputs split to accumulators
     28             X = np.concatenate([X, inpt[np.newaxis, np.newaxis]], axis=0)

<__array_function__ internals> in pad(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraypad.py in pad(array, pad_width, mode, **kwargs)
    746 
    747     # Broadcast to shape (array.ndim, 2)
--> 748     pad_width = _as_pairs(pad_width, array.ndim, as_index=True)
    749 
    750     if callable(mode):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraypad.py in _as_pairs(x, ndim, as_index)
    517 
    518     if as_index and x.min() < 0:
--> 519         raise ValueError("index can't contain negative values")
    520 
    521     # Converting the array with `tolist` seems to improve performance

ValueError: index can't contain negative values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED] Bugs fixed. The implementation below should now give desired output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = {
    'id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
'speed1': [17.63,17.63,0.17,1.41,0.61,0.32,0.18,0.43,0.30,0.46,0.75,0.37],
'speed2': [0.00,-0.09,1.24,-0.80,-0.29,-0.14,0.25,-0.13,0.16,0.29,-0.38,0.27],
'acc1': [0.00,0.01,-2.04,0.51,0.15,0.39,-0.38,0.29,0.13,-0.67,0.65,0.52],
'acc2': [29.03,56.12,18.49,11.85,36.75,27.52,81.08,51.06,19.85,10.76,14.51,24.27],
'label' : [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3] }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)

def transform(dataframe, chunk_size=5):
    
    grouped = dataframe.groupby('id')

    # initialize accumulators
    X, y = np.zeros([0, 1, chunk_size, 4]), np.zeros([0,])

    # loop over each group (df[df.id==1] and df[df.id==2])
    for _, group in grouped:

        inputs = group.loc[:, 'speed1':'acc2'].values
        label = group.loc[:, 'label'].values[0]

        # calculate number of splits
        N = (len(inputs)-1) // chunk_size

        if N > 0:
            inputs = np.array_split(
                 inputs, [chunk_size + (chunk_size*i) for i in range(N)])
        else:
            inputs = [inputs]

        # loop over splits
        for inpt in inputs:
            inpt = np.pad(
                inpt, [(0, chunk_size-len(inpt)),(0, 0)], 
                mode='constant')
            # add each inputs split to accumulators
            X = np.concatenate([X, inpt[np.newaxis, np.newaxis]], axis=0)
            y = np.concatenate([y, label[np.newaxis]], axis=0) 

    return X, y

X, y = transform(df)

print('X shape =', X.shape)
print('X =', X)
print('Y shape =', y.shape)
print('Y =', y)

# >> out:
# X shape = (3, 1, 5, 4)
# X = [[[[17.63  0.    0.   29.03]
#    [17.63 -0.09  0.01 56.12]
#    [ 0.17  1.24 -2.04 18.49]
#    [ 1.41 -0.8   0.51 11.85]
#    [ 0.61 -0.29  0.15 36.75]]]
#
#
#  [[[ 0.32 -0.14  0.39 27.52]
#    [ 0.18  0.25 -0.38 81.08]
#    [ 0.43 -0.13  0.29 51.06]
#    [ 0.3   0.16  0.13 19.85]
#    [ 0.46  0.29 -0.67 10.76]]]
#
#
#  [[[ 0.75 -0.38  0.65 14.51]
#    [ 0.37  0.27  0.52 24.27]
#    [ 0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
#    [ 0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
#    [ 0.    0.    0.    0.  ]]]]
# Y shape = (3,)
# Y = [3. 3. 3.]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, the input to my neural network is of size `TotalInput= (175573, 1, 100, 4)`, that's I have `175573` arrays, each of shape `(1, 100,4)`. I give an example of size `(1, 5, 4)` to simplify my question.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Why do you need an extra dimension at axis 1? (_, 1, _, _).

Comment: I've updated the code above (the output is now (3, 1, 5, 4))

Comment: Thank you. preparing data input to a conv-net, the goal is to transform input to grid-like shape `(1,100,4)` 1-segment (length) of 100-data points (width) and 4-motion characteristics ((channels).

Comment: I have noticed 2-bugs with the function in this answer as shown in the question edit. Can you please help fix this?

Comment: I will try to help.

Comment: Note: I've updated the answer/implementation twice. After the first update it still had some issues/bugs, but after the second update it should now be fine.

Comment: many thanks. can you educate me what was the problem in the first case, when python issues `index can't contain negative values`? Just curious to now.

Comment: There was a problem with how the split(s) were made with `np.array_split` (the array was split at the wrong places), resulting in `chunk_size-len(inpt)` being a negative value (which was passed to the argument `pad_width` (second argument) of `np.pad`, raising the `ValueError`)).